# How to create a custom boot screen in android before building the source?

Tags: android, customization

How can i change the default boot image in android in OS level. I am making a customized android build(I use source of froyo) . I want to replace the existing image with my custom image. I have read somewhere that we have to make some changes to frameworks/base/libs/surfaceflinger/BootAnimation.cpp. But that file seems missing.

Can someone give some links to tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=753788

Tools You Need:

- Image Manipulation Tool (Photoshop, Gimp, MSPaint, anything that can save bmp files really.
- NBIMG command-line splash<-->image converter tool
- Zipping tool (7zip, winzip, anything that can put files in a .zip)
- android-info.txt (http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13993144320556&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=18c17f5b-3eb1-4435-bf7b-87363f1263b7&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D753788&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcjock.com%2Fsplash%2Fandroid-info.txt&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Freview%2Flow-quality-posts%2F4728175&title=%5BHOW%20TO%5D%20Create%20custom%20hboot-flashable%20SPLASH1%20images%20-%20xda-developers&txt=This%20file)

How-To:

- Download and extract the files linked above and place them somewhere familiar to you.
- In your image creation/manipulation tool, create a new image. Set the image size to 480x800. (If you already have an image in mind, open that and resize it)
- Create/modify/customize the image however you like.
- Save the image as splash1.bmp file. Ensure that you are saving the file as a 24bit RGB color bitmap. To make things easy, save the image in the same folder where you extracted the nbimg tool.
- Open a command or terminal window and CD to your nbimg folder.
- Type in the following command: nbimg -F splash1.bmp -w 480 -h 800

If successful, nbimg should have created an nb file called 'splash1.bmp.nb'.

- Rename 'splash1.bmp.nb' to 'splash1.img'.
- Take your newly created splash1.img file and the 'android-info.txt' that you downloaded earlier, and place it in a new ZIP file called 'PB31IMG.zip'.
- Place your newly created PB31IMG.zip on the root of your SD card, and reboot to hboot. (adb reboot oem-42)
  C
  If everything went smoothly, you should be prompted to install your custom splash1.

Comment: This is to replace the boot screen in an android device. But i am making a custom build and testing it on beagle board. I need to have a version of android which can be installed in devices and it will show our custom image as boot screen. Thanks for ur reply anyway.